# Warum wird hier "mit" mit "sind" benutzt?

Tags: preposition

Aus *Kryptografie verständlich* von Parr und Pelzl:

> Schlüsselerzeugung und -verteilung sind in der Praxis **mit** die
>   wichtigsten, aber oft auch die schwersten Aspekte in einem
>   Sicherheitssystem.

Ist ein Regel im Spiel oder gibt es einen Grund für die Verwendung von »mit«?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mit bezieht sich nicht auf sind, sondern bringt zum Ausdruck, dass es andere, im Satz nicht erwähnte, Aspekte gibt, die ebenfalls eine Rolle spielen.

> Schlüsselerzeugung und -verteilung sind in der Praxis die wichtigsten, aber oft auch die schwersten Aspekte in einem Sicherheitssystem.

Hier sind ausschließlich die beiden Aspekte der Schlüsselerzeugung und -verteilung gemeint.

Answer (score 5):

Die Konstruktion

> <*Etwas*> ist mit der/die/das <*Superlativ*> <*Bezeichnung einer Klasse (Nominativ singular)*>

also z.B.:

> Die Wärmekapazität ist mit der wichtigste Parameter sensibler Speichermaterialien.
>   Das Hören von Lauten ist mit die stärkste Sinneswahrnehmung, die der Mensch besitzt.
>   Das Hotel Rappen ist mit das beste Hotel in Rothenburg.

ist relativ neu. Ich würde sie noch nicht als *standardsprachlich* bezeichnen. Es bleibt abzuwarten, ob das eine vorübergehende Modeerscheinung ist, oder ob sich diese Konstruktion noch etablieren wird.

---

**Bedeutung**

Die obige Konstruktion drückt dasselbe aus wie diese Konstruktion:

> <*Etwas*> gehört zu den <*Suberlativ*> <*Mitglieder einer Klasse (Dativ plural)*>

Die genannten Beispiele lassen sich also in konservativer Sprache so formulieren:

> Die Wärmekapazität gehört zu den wichtigsten Parametern sensibler Speichermaterialien.
>   Das Hören von Lauten gehört zu den stärksten Sinneswahrnehmungen, die der Mensch besitzt.
>   Das Hotel Rappen gehört zu den besten Hotels in Rothenburg.

Der in der Frage zitierte Satz kann also auch so formuliert werden:

> Schlüsselerzeugung und -verteilung gehören in der Praxis zu den wichtigsten, aber oft auch zu den schwersten Aspekten in einem Sicherheitssystem.