# Infinite form of "meldet er Ernst gleich mit an"

Tags: separable-verb, prefix, conjugation

In this sentence,

*Als Max einen Fallschirmsprung plant, meldet er Ernst gleich mit an.*

I am very confused regarding the position of *mit*. What role does *mit* play here? How would the infinitive of this phrase be? *Jemanden mit anmelden?* I don't think it is a preposition as it doesn't precede Ernst, so I reckon it has to be part of anmelden somehow.

Comment: You're totally right that *mit* is not a preposition but an adverb here. Further reading regarding the adverb *mit*: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mit_neben_damit

Comment: Thank you, if I understood it correctly, when "mit" is used as an adverb, it occupies a position right before the separable prefix, right?
Also, would it be correct to remove the "mit" in the sentence and have it be correct?
Such as "Er meldet Ernst gleich an"?, the infinitive would be "jemanden anmelden" it seems.

Comment: I made my answer an actual answer. Questions to other aspects of *mit* + verb (the latter two are in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53166/, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46364/, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mit* is not a preposition, but an adverb here. See [the Duden page](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mit_neben_damit) for a detailed listing of several use cases.

I will answer your questions separately:

### What role does *mit* play here?

I think the most important function of *mit* is to express togetherness:

> Als Max einen Fallschirmsprung plant, meldet er Ernst gleich *mit sich zusammen* an.

However, you can think of *mit* also as a synonym for *ebenfalls* or *auch* here:

> Als Max einen Fallschirmsprung plant, meldet er Ernst gleich *ebenfalls* an.

> Als Max einen Fallschirmsprung plant, meldet er Ernst *auch* gleich an.

(As you see, *auch* would have a different position in the sentence, but I guess this needs to be discussed in another question.)

### How would the infinitive of this phrase be? *Jemanden mit anmelden*?

This one is a bit difficult because *mit* can cross the line from adverb to verb prefix. The Duden article I linked above says that the adverbial *mit* (*jmdn. (mit) anmelden* ~ *jmdn. (ebenfalls) anmelden*) becomes a (separable) prefix (like in *mitfühlen*) when the connection is **persistent**. I think that doesn't explain all variations, but unfortunately, I haven't come up with a better criterium yet.

In this case, that means the infinite is *(jmdn.) anmelden*. But a verb like *(jmdn.) mitanmelden* is totally thinkable! With *mit*, it depends always on the context. In case of doubt, usually both perceptions are possible.

### When "mit" is used as an adverb, it occupies a position right before the separable prefix, right?

At the time of writing I can't think of a counterexample, so I suppose it always does as a rule.

### Would it be correct to remove the *mit* in the sentence and have it be correct? Such as *Er meldet Ernst gleich an*?

The sentence remains grammatical, but one important information is lost: *Max plante einen Fallschirmsprung und meldete Ernst **mit** an* implies that Max registered himself as well. This stems from the fact that *anmelden* can be interpreted as part of *planen*. Without *mit*, the sentence reads as if Max would register only Ernst or even plan the jump *for* Ernst.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand a lot better what role "mit" plays here.

Answer (score 1):

#### *mit* = "as well"

> *Max meldet Ernst mit an.* "Max enrolls Ernst as well." (Max enrolls both himself and Ernst.)
> *Max meldet Ernst an.* "Max enrolls Ernst." (Max enrolls only Ernst, but not himself.)